# Git hub actions deploy pages throws error

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

I am receiving the error " No uploaded artifact was found! Please check if there are any errors at build step, or uploaded artifact name is correct." please let me know what is missing

```
name: MTA - Accessibility Tests for E2E

on:
  schedule: #This cron job is run every morning 2 AM
    - cron: "0 2 * * *"
  workflow_dispatch: {}
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]

permissions:
  contents: write
  pages: write # to deploy to Pages
  id-token: write # to verify the deployment originates from an appropriate source

env:
  GLOBAL_VARIABLE: true

jobs:
  e2e-tests:
    timeout-minutes: 60
    runs-on:
      - self-hosted
      - vm:m5.large
    container:
      image: public.docker.nexus3.auiag.corp/playwright:v1.25.0-focal
    

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: "21.6.2"

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Download browsers (for playwright v1.38 and later)
        run: npx playwright install --with-deps

      - name: Set build failure flag to true
        run: echo "GLOBAL_VARIABLE=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: MTA Env-  DEV, Run Playwright tests for Online Account E2E
        run: |
          npm run test:dev:a11y:mta:n || echo "GLOBAL_VARIABLE=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        continue-on-error: true
      - name: MTA Env-  DEV, Run Playwright tests for Online Account E2E
        run: |
          npm run test:dev:a11y:mta:a || echo "GLOBAL_VARIABLE=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        continue-on-error: true
      - name: MTA Env- Dev , Run Playwright tests for Online Account E2E
        run: |
          npm run test:dev:a11y:mta:d || echo "GLOBAL_VARIABLE=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        continue-on-error: true

      - name: Conditional step
        run: |
          if [ ${{ env.GLOBAL_VARIABLE }} = false ]; then
            echo "GLOBAL_VARIABLE is 'false'. Failing the workflow."
            exit 1
          fi
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        if: always()
        with:
          name: test-artifacts-oa
          path: |
            axe-html-report-mta
            axe-html-report-mta
            axe-html-report-mta
          retention-days: 30

      - name: Publish MTA to Github pages
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        if: always()
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./axe-html-report-mta
          destination_dir: accessibility/mta/
          keep_files: true

      - name: Publish MTA to Github pages
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        if: always()
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./axe-html-report-mta
          destination_dir: accessibility/mta/
          keep_files: true

      - name: Publish MTA to Github pages
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        if: always()
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./axe-html-report-mta
          destination_dir: accessibility/mta/
          keep_files: true

      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        if: always()
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v2
```

I am receiving the below error

Error: No uploaded artifact was found! Please check if there are any errors at build step, or uploaded artifact name is correct.

The above error occurs on "Deploy to GitHub Pages"

Please let me know the resons and ways to fix it. Thanks